# Drag images on Google Maps wrong position displayed on the map

Tags: google-maps, drag-and-drop

Here is the JS code. I have two different images that I'm going to place as a marker on the map called DRAGGABLE and DRAGGABLE2.
The map load a kml file.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#draggable").draggable({helper: 'clone',
stop: function(e) {
    var point=new google.maps.Point(e.pageX -27,e.pageY -106);
    var ll= overlay.getProjection().fromContainerPixelToLatLng(point);
    placeMarker(ll, 'alert.png');
    }
});

$("#draggable2").draggable({helper: 'clone',
stop: function(e) {
    var point=new google.maps.Point(e.pageX - 27,e.pageY -106);
    var ll=overlay.getProjection().fromContainerPixelToLatLng(point);
    placeMarker(ll, 'facebook.png');
    }
});
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var map;
var overlay;
var markers = {};
function initialize() {

  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 3,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
        var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('test.kml');
    ctaLayer.setMap(map);

  overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();
  overlay.draw = function() {};
  overlay.setMap(map);
}

function placeMarker(location,imgdrag) {
  var currentMrkMap; 
  currentMrkMap = parseInt(document.getElementById('mrkadd').value);
  currentMrkMap += 1;
  document.getElementById('mrkadd').value = currentMrkMap;
  document.getElementById('mrkelements').innerHTML += 'TestCodeHtmlIntoDIV';


  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        id: 'marker_' + currentMrkMap, 
        position: location, 
        draggable: true,
        map: map,
        icon:'img/'+imgdrag

  });
  id = 'marker_' + currentMrkMap;
  markers[id] = marker;

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: 'Add element <br><textarea id="txtAr" name="txtAr" rows="5" ></textarea><br>'
  });
  infowindow.open(map,marker);

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',function() {
      var coords = this.getPosition();
      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: 'Add element <br><textarea id="txtAr" name="txtAr" rows="5" >' +  coords +'</textarea><br>'
      });
      infowindow.open(map,marker);
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "dragend", function() {
      var coordinates = document.getElementById("txtAr");
      var coords = this.getPosition();
      coordinates.value= coords.lat() + ' '+ coords.lng();

  });

}
</script>
```

Css Code. The body and the sidebar are from bootstrap.

```
<style type="text/css"> 
  body {
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
  }
  .sidebar-nav {
    padding: 9px 0;
  }
  #map_canvas {         
    width: 100%;
    height: 530px;  
  }
</style>
```

And HTML code is based on Bootstrap. The portion where I our the map is like this

```
<div class="span9"> 
    <div class="hero-unit">             
        <div id="map_canvas"></div>            
     </div>           
</div><!--/span-->
```

Comment: The answer is that something is different between the example and your application, but as you have given no data about your app it's not possible to say what. I'd make a guess that your map is not sized to 100% of the page, though.

Comment: Indeed the map is not 100% of the page. I also thought that that was the problem. IS my solution to modifing the POINT manually a good solution or can cause problem with different browser or operating systems ?

Comment: Can't say. It's possible that different browsers or OS will require a different adjustment. Please update the question to give a link to a demonstrator: there may well be a generic solution to what you are trying to do.

Comment: It's part of a project that is running local. I can post some code in order to show how everything works. Is that ok ?

Comment: Given that you need to make the map public to comply with the Terms (unless you have bought a Premier licence), why not put the code live somewhere? Even jsfiddle.net can work.